# Grepper VSCode Extension asking to log in but already logged in

Tags: vscode-extensions

I use the Grepper extension in my VSCode and it used to work without any problems.

Recently I'm having a problem that every time I select Grepper in Command Pallete and type a search, VSCode returns an error "You need to Login to your Grepper account to use this feature. Login by clicking the Grepper Icon on the activity bar to the left."

[image: Error Screenshot]

My extension is already logged in, as you can see in the screenshot.

I've already tried uninstalling and installing the extension, logging out and logging in again,
restart VSCode, update VSCode, test on VSCode Insiders, but none of that helped.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?